# MKMapView maximal value for distance?

Tags: mkmapview, distance, region, mkcoordinateregion, mkcoordinatespan

I have a problem with `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance`.
I try to specify the distance value via a slider in the preferences of my iPad App.

When I put in more that 963 as int or float, the mapView don't apply the value and takes it's own value.

Is there any maximum value or can I edit the MKMapView that it will take values about 10.000 meters?

Thanks, kind regards, Julian

***Edit***

Here's some code on request:

```
  // PreferencesView
- (IBAction)changeZoomDidEnd:(UISlider *)sender
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[sender value] forKey:@"defaultZoom"];
}
  // MapView
- (IBAction)zoomToLocation:(id)sender
{
    defaultZoom = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"defaultZoom"] intValue];
    [mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, defaultZoom, defaultZoom) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code?  There is no maximum but the map view will adjust the requested region as necessary.  10,000 meters is not a problem.  What is the slider's maximumValue set to?

Comment: Thanks for answer, edited original post, added some code

Comment: Looks like that should work.  In changeZoomDidEnd, log the value using `NSLog(@"changeZoomDidEnd: [sender value] = %f", [sender value]);`.  In zoomToLocation, _after_ setting defaultZoom, log it using `NSLog(@"zoomToLocation: defaultZoom = %d", defaultZoom);`.  See what values get logged.  Is zoomToLocation ever called _before_ the slider is changed?

Comment: I'm already logging the values. They are all good. Yes, it _is_ called before. The settings are one modalViewController, the mapView is in another.